# Gradle(v4.8) project sync failed android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

As soon as i imported android project in android studio it shows

> Gradle Project sync failed
>
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.8

I already updated gradle to latest version i.e v4.8 & android studio is also latest.

Project level build.gradle :-
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.8'

Below i attached screenshot of error :-

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Can someone tell what am i supposed to do. I have already checked most of the same threads here & tried them all but nothing seems to be working now.

Comment: can you update your question with project level build.gradle?

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean the build.gradle which contains `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle...`

Comment: edited the original question

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the gradle version and gradle plugin version

The latest Gradle version available is `4.8` but the gradle plugin version is `3.1.2`. In your project level build.gradle ensure the configuration is:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @GamesLover for the context of the question, if the answer was useful, then remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: after everything i am not able to solve this error - "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-L' in: C:\Users\r\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk "

Comment: @GamesLover looks like you haven't installed android-L in your SdkManager

Comment: In the Android SDK tool, I can see "Android 5.0" (API level 21) already installed.

Comment: @GamesLover have you checked answer from `Hasnat Shah` in the SO ?

Comment: @GamesLover create a new question with all the information. Highlight the `SO` answers you have referred in the question. so that someone can add more information to it.

Comment: @GamesLover just try `Invalidate caceh and Restart` before doing that

Comment: I did invalidate cache & all but still getting same error so asked new question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781875/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-l